# kafka-connect not being able to communicate through TLS with MSK

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using kafka-connect deployed as a statefulSet, I am using [confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:6.2.2](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-images/tree/master/kafka-connect-base) long story short: when I use PLAINTEXT MSK endpoint, the ensure check goes as normal and it connects to the broker, while using TLS fails with no relevant error. It is just stuck in:

```
===> User uid=1000(appuser) gid=1000(appuser) groups=1000(appuser) ===> Configuring ... ===> Running preflight checks ... ===> Check if Kafka is healthy ... SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/slf4j-simple-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation. SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.confluent.admin.utils.cli.KafkaReadyCommand). log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Any information regarding it? is TLS supported? I took a look at the ensure stage and clearly saw that it is supposed [supported](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-images/blob/master/kafka-connect-base/include/etc/confluent/docker/ensure#L21-L28). Is there any way to make that work? and if needed, can I skip the ensure stage? is there any flag permitting it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding setting CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL environment variable to ssl